# JavaScript NaN with HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a small maths game with the code below, however I keep getting  Not-A-Number error everytime the prompt comes up. i'm not entirely sure what the problem is. I have tried to round the number but it doesn't help the situation. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```js
function start() {

  // define questions
  var question = []; 
  // define answers
  var answer = [];
  // store user input
  var input = [];

  var score = 0;

  // when the user enters their answer it is stored by input for every prompt
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    var operator = [ '+', '-', '*', '/' ];
    var ops = [Math.floor(Math.random() * operator.length)];

    question[i] = randNum + ops[operator] + randNum;

    answer[i] = randNum + ops[operator] + randNum;

    input[i] = prompt(question[i]);
  }

  // check the answer against the stored answer, display one of either from if statement

  for(var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
    if (answer[i] == input[i]) {
      var outputResult = document.getElementById("write");
      outputResult.innerHTML += "<p class = corr>Question " + (i+1) + " is correct.</p>";
    } else {
      outputResult.innerHTML += "<p class = incorr>Question " + (i+1) + " is incorrect. The answer should have been " + answer[i] + ".</p>";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
 <h1>Maths Game!</h1>
</header>

<button onclick="start()">Start</button> <!-- start game -->

<div id="write">
</div>

<div class="score"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: as it is now you will always have the same two numbers added or subtracted from one another in your equation...you should do a second randNum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reference the operator array incorrectly. Try this:

```
var operator = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
var ops = Math.floor(Math.random() * operator.length);

question[i] = randNum + operator[ops] + randNum;
answer[i] = eval(question[i]);
input[i] = prompt(question[i]);
```

Comment: `answer[i]` won't be what OP expects, though - it will be the same string as the prompt (e.g. `"3*3"`) instead of the expected answer (e.g. `"9"`).

Comment: @PaulRoub Spotted that, fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines create NaN in each index of question/answer ARRAYs:

```
question[i] = randNum + ops[operator] + randNum;
answer[i] = randNum + ops[operator] + randNum;
```

Because:

```
ops[operator]
```

is not a Number;